# How can I position my Button at the right side of my view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, alignment

I want to position a Button at the far right side of my view but everything I have tried from Google searches hasn't worked. Currently it looks like this

[image: Screen shot]

The xml code for this is below

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderFrame"
        android:id="@+id/headerPanel">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/LeftFrame">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/backBttn"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:text="&lt;"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderFrame"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#ff9d9d9d"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/forwardBttn"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:text="&gt;"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderFrame"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#ff9d9d9d"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/CheckOutBttn"
            android:text="Return to Checkout"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                
            android:background="@drawable/template_green" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is your Fault

in your xml you set `android:layout_alignParentRight` which is Relative Layout Property .But you using Linear Layout .

**android:layout_alignParentRight** :
If true, makes the right edge of this view match the right edge of the parent. Accommodates right margin.

So set your parent layout **`Relative Layout instead Linear Layout`** .

Please set ***2 Textview and Button in same RelativeLayout***

Comment: Thank you, I re-arranged my xml and replaced Linear layout with Relative Layout and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this layout, if you want to play around the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/backBttn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="#ff9d9d9d"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forwardBttn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ff9d9d9d"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text=">"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/CheckOutBttn"
        android:text="Return to Checkout"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/template_green" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hopes it helps you somehow and Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score -1):

just change your top `<LinearLayout>` to `<RelativeLayout>` your problem is solved

Comment: Your logic is perfect .But dont know why down-voted your answer .

Answer (score -1):

As root of your layout you have to use `<RelativeLayout>` instead of `<LinearLayout>`

Comment: I don't know, mystery